# string variable as sqlite table name

Tags: python, sqlite

i need to create an sqlite table with the name of a global string variable, but i cant seem to find a way to insert the variable to the CREATE TABLE command.

is there a way to do so, or after creating a table with a placeholder name rename it to the variable?

the variable is an user input so i cannot name it in advance.

im coding in python.

Comment: You can use simple string concatenation.  `"CREATE TABLE " + tablename`

Comment: It's not really clear what you are after — how are you going to reference that global variable if not by name and if you know the name, why can't you use a string? Can you add a little code to clarify?

Comment: the variable is created by user input, sorry for not clarifying i'll update the post

Comment: Be careful to sanitise the user input before you glue it into an SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory')
cur = con.cursor()
TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
cur.execute(f'CREATE TABLE {TABLE_NAME} (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
    NAME VARCHAR(200))')
```

And yes, that also works with `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

F-strings like the one in Stefan's answers are great, and you can find a lot of use cases when working with SQL queries. Just be aware f-strings are available starting from Python 3.6 - if you are on an older version you will need to use the old %-formatting or str.format() methods, or simple string concatenation as already noted